# How to retrieve data from firestore by adding where condition based on a field inside an object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

Im using firebase firestore as a backend database for my react native project.
I need to retrieve data from database.It works well if the code is as below

```
unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('messages').where('user', "==", this.props.user.uid).onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate)
```

But How I can retrieve data if the 'user' field is an object with a field of id?

Answer (score 1):

If the document has been created with an object like:

```
  var obj = {
    user: {
      id: '234567'
    },
    otherField: 'abcd'
  };
```

and for example created with:

```
  docRef.set(obj);
```

you can query it as follows:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('messages').where('user.id', "==", this.props.user.uid).onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

simply instead of using .where() you could use .doc('but your id here')
so in your case, it will be

```
.doc(obj.user.id).onSnap .....
```